# boost qi::phrase_parse reads only first element

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit-qi

I've implemented simple ascii parser using `boost::spirit`.
target ascii file looks like

```
n

0 23 45 10.0 0.5

.....

n-1 x y .....
```

but it returns in measure_list only 1 element

if I am trying to read ASCII as a simple `vector<double>` instead of structured for example - it works fine. Whats wrong?

```
struct measure
{
   int id;
   double x, y, size_, angle;
} 

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(measure, (int, id)(double, x)(double, y)(double, size_)(double, angel))

typedef std::vector<measure> data_t;

void RelativeMeasure(string filename)
        {
                clear();

                if(!filesystem::exists(filename)) return;

                file_name = filename;



                ifstream calibration_file(filename);

                if(calibration_file.is_open())
                {
                        int key_count;
                        calibration_file >> key_count;

                        istreambuf_iterator<char> eos;
                        istreambuf_iterator<char> it(calibration_file);

                        std::string strver(it, eos);

                        std::vector<measure> measure_list;
                        measure_list.reserve(100000);

                        qi::phrase_parse(strver.begin(), strver.end(), (qi::int_ > qi::double_ > qi::double_ > qi::double_ > qi::double_) % qi::eol, qi::blank, measure_list);

                        for each(auto measure in measure_list) key_list.push_back(KeyPoint(measure.x, measure.y, measure.size_, measure.angel));
}
```

Comment: `(double, angel))` I think you mean to say `(double, angle))`

Comment: Please construct an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It's very hard (if not impossible) to tell what could be broken in your real code from pseudocode that wouldn't compile even if it were complete. It could be anything from malformed input data (empty lines?) to undefined behavior in another part of the code that messes up the parser.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most likely culprit that I see is that you don't eat the newline after `n`. Perhaps also use `+qi::eol` as the delimiter.

But that doesn't explain that you'd read the first entry.

You could simplify things by using the streaming API (using `boost::spirit::istream_iterator` multi-pass adaptor under the hood):

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8a04db444d19c814)**

```
void RelativeMeasure(std::string filename)
{
    std::ifstream calfile(filename, std::ios::binary);

    int key_count;
    std::vector<measure> measure_list;

    using namespace qi;
    if (
        calfile >> std::noskipws >> phrase_match(int_, blank, key_count)
        && calfile >> phrase_match(qi::repeat(key_count)[int_ > double_ > double_ > double_ > double_ > +eol], blank, measure_list)
    )
    {
        std::vector<KeyPoint> key_list;
        key_list.reserve(measure_list.size());
        // using a converting constructor (why not parse into this at once?)
        std::copy(measure_list.begin(), measure_list.end(), back_inserter(key_list));
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot. phrase_match with +qi::eol works correctly